# deploy symfony server error

Tags: symfony-1.4

hi
i have this error when i try to login:
he look for a columns slug in sfguarduser table but there is no columns
00 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's.slug' in 'field list'

i have another error when i try to acces to a form of registration

500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
Unknown record property / related component "Profile" on "sfGuardUser"

i added manually the column slug to the table sfguard user and I am getting this error
- Unknown record property / related component 
"permissions" on "sfGuardUser", referer - in my error_log when I 
attempt to login to my symfony 1.4 app after deployment. I do not get 
it on my local machine. 
When I submit the login form, Symfony throws a 500 error. If I refresh 
the page, the login form is reposted and I am logged in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this column already in your schema.yml - if please rebuild your models and forms

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```